# Spring MVC null attribute in my @modelAttribute object sended to the controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I'm trying to use @modelAttribute to send my model attributes to the controller

my model contains many attributes (String, Integer,..) one of them is an object that i want to retrieve from a select tag.
the problem is when i pass the modelattribute to the controller my object is Null

JSP:

```
<form:form method="post" action="saveUorg.html"  modelAttribute="uorg" >
<table >
<tr>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Nom abregé</th>
    <th>timbre</th>
    <th>Date début effet</th>
    <th>Date fin effet</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input  path="nom" name="nom"/></td>
    <td><input  path="nomAbrege" name="nomAbrege"/></td>
    <td><input  path="timbre" name="timbre"/></td>
    <td><input  type="date" path="dateDebutEffet" name="dateDebutEffet"/></td>
    <td><input  type="date" path="dateFinEffet" name="dateFinEffet"/></td>
 </tr>
</table> 
<table >
<tr>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>Unité père</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input  path="email" name="email"/></td>
    <td><select  path="refUniteOrganisParent">
        <option  value="-"> --- </option> 
      <c:forEach items="${listeuos}" var="uorgg" varStatus="status" >
        <option  value="${uorgg}">${uorgg} </option> 
      </c:forEach>
    </select></td>
 </tr>
```

this is my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/saveUorg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveUorg(@ModelAttribute("uorg") UorgVO uorg,BindingResult result){


        System.out.println("RefUniteOrganisParent:" +uorg.getRefUniteOrganisParent());


        return new ModelAndView("view","uorg",uorg);    
    }
```

refUniteOragnisParent is the null object, when i print the content result in my controller of uorg.refUniteOrganisParent the result is null.
Thank's in advance for help.

Comment: Signature of the controller method? Class?

Comment: @zeroflagL i edited the post and put my controller method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your `select` tag does not have a name attribute.

Second when a form is submitted the controller only gets strings. Spring has to convert every parameter to the type you want. It has built-in converters for simple types like `Integer` or `Boolean`, but not for complex types, not to mention your own types.

So if the attribute `refUniteOrganisParent` is an object and only represented by a single value (the `option` value) you need to implement a converter that creates an instance based on this value:

```
public class StringToMyType implements Converter<String, MyType> { ...
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert

And you need to register your Converter:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-customize

Answer (score 0):

In your controller,the model attribute object should be like this:

```
        @RequestMapping(value ="/saveUorg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public ModelAndView saveUorg(@ModelAttribute("uorg") UorgVO uorg,BindingResult result){

          ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("view");              
          mav.addObject("uorg",uorg);
          System.out.println("RefUniteOrganisParent:" +uorg.getRefUniteOrganisParent());

    return mav;    
}
```